# Can't get real-ip from nginx/varnish to pass on, always shows 127.0.0.1

Tags: varnish, nginx-reverse-proxy, real-ip

I would like to have the real-IP shows up in the server/magento but it keeps falling back to 127.0.0.1

The server is setup as follow:
- Varnish listen on port 80
- Nginx listen on port 8080
- The SSL traffic are passed onto port 80
The final website it takes to is a magento 2 site

Nginx is version 1.14.0 with with-http_realip_module

My Nginx server block is as follow:

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
  server   unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm-magento.sock;
}

server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name example.example.com;

    set $MAGE_ROOT /opt/magento/public_html;
    set $MAGE_MODE developer; # or production

    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;
    include /opt/magento/public_html/nginx.conf.sample;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.example.com-8080-error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.example.com-8080access.log;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.example.com/chain.pem;
    include snippets/ssl.conf;
    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:80;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
    }
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.example.com-443access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.example.com-443error.log;
}
```

My Nginx access log (8080access.log) shows 127.0.0.1 for all entries
the error log (8080-error.log) also shows 127.0.0.1 for client
The SSL traffic, 443 logs, is showing the actual IP.

Below is my Nginx configuration output:

`configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/nginx-FIJPpj/nginx-1.14.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fPIC' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module`

I have tried to add the following code to /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
set_real_ip_from   127.0.0.1;
real_ip_header      X-Forwarded-For;
```

And
    set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
to /etc/varnish/default.vcl, but since it is a magento specific version of Varnish, I placed it like below:

```
sub vcl_recv {
set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
if (req.method == "PURGE") {
    if (client.ip !~ purge) {
        return (synth(405, "Method not allowed"));
    }
    # To use the X-Pool header for purging varnish during automated deployments, make sure the X-Pool header
    # has been added to the response in your backend server config. This is used, for example, by the
    # capistrano-magento2 gem for purging old content from varnish during it's deploy routine.
    if (!req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern && !req.http.X-Pool) {
        return (synth(400, "X-Magento-Tags-Pattern or X-Pool header required"));
```

After restarting both services I am still getting the same 127.0.0.1 in the log as well as in Magento 2.

I am puzzled, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, the following has to be added to the server block:

```
set_real_ip_from 10.0.0.0/8; #your ip
real_ip_header X-Real-IP;
real_ip_recursive on;
```

Original answer was found here:
https://calvin.me/forward-ip-addresses-when-using-nginx-proxy/